# Terminology for a function, that "is" a morphism in some concrete category

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Suppose I've got a category $\mathcal{A}$ equipped with an obvious faithful functor $\underline{} : \mathcal{A} \to \mathsf{Set}$; $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ and a function $\tilde{f} : \underline{A} \to \underline{B}$. Is there a nicer way to say:

> There is a (unique) morphism $f : A \to B$ in $\mathcal{A}$ with $\tilde{f} = \underline{f}$.

---

Claiming, that $f = \tilde{f}$ is out of the question (even if it is correct, it is evil). I'm thinking something along the lines of:

> $\tilde{f}$ [somethings] a morphism $f : A \to B$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

but I'm not sure, if there is terminology like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "lifts uniquely to"? But because lifts are unique I think the abuse of notation "is" is fine. E.g. I'm happy to say that some function between abelian groups "is" a morphism of abelian groups, because that's a property of a function.

Comment: Actually.... I might just literally use " 'is' " as a verb and explain what it means. Didn't think of that!